# $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is positively oriented iff $\det(A) > 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ are three linearly independent vectors in
>   $\mathbb{R}^3$. Suppose $A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc} | & | & | \\
>  v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\ | & | & | \end{array} \right)$. Show that
>   $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is positively oriented iff $\det(A) > 0$. Also show
>   that $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is negatively oriented iff $\det(A)<0$.

So I know that the $\det(A)$ can be computed as $v_1\cdot (v_2\times v_3)$.

For the first question, I start by assuming that $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is positively oriented. This means that $v_3$ lies in the same half-space as $v_1\times v_2$ (by definition). How does this definition show that $v_1\cdot (v_2\times v_3) > 0$? Similarly, if $v_1\cdot (v_2\times v_3) > 0$, why does this mean that $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is positively oriented?

Comment: What is your exact definition of *positively oriented*?

Comment: @PeterFranek The plane $span\{v_1,v_2\}$ divides $\mathbb{R}^3$ into two opposite sides, or half-spaces. On one side is the half-space containing $v_1\times v_2$, and on the other side is the half-space containing $-v_1\times v_2$. If $v_3$ lies in the first half-space, then we say $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is positively oriented, and if in the second, it's negatively oriented.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then you can use the fact that the determinant also equals $v_3\cdot (v_1\times v_2)$ and $v_3$ directs to the same halfplane as $v_1\times v_2$, iff the scalar product is positive.

Comment: @PeterFranek How do we know it directs to the same half-space if $v_3\cdot (v_1\times v_2)$ is positive?

Comment: The scalar product of two vectors is positive iff their angle is smaller than 90 degrees: that's quite elementary and easy to check (unless the angle is defined by means of scalar product)

Comment: @PeterFranek That helps. I guess my next question is why the angle must be smaller than 90 degrees. It seems like we should be able to go through 180 degrees, but my conceptual understanding may be off.

Comment: The scalar product is zero iff the vectors are perpendicular to each other. If you believe that the scalar product varies continuously with the vectors, then $v\cdot w$ must have the same sign for a fixed $v$ and $w$ varying from one halfspace in $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus v^\perp$. Further, if you know that $v\cdot v$ is positive, then you see on which halfspace the sign is positive and on which it is negative.